# Xcode 12 won't allow ⌘⌥← / ⌘⌥→ shortcuts for “Show Previous Tab” / “Show Next Tab”

Tags: xcode

I am trying to customize the Xcode 12.2 keyboard shortcuts for **"Show Previous Tab"** and **"Show Next Tab"**. These are the new *document* tabs that were introduced in Xcode 12, as opposed to the old *window* tabs. (The document tab bar is below the window tab bar.)

When I go to Preferences > Key Bindings, and try to record shortcuts for "Show Previous Tab" and "Show Next Tab", the settings panel records **⌘⌥← as ⌘← and ⌘⌥→ as ⌘→**. Basically, the option key disappears.

This is a problem *only* for those two shortcuts. If I try to customize "Show Previous *Window* Tab" and "Show Next *Window* Tab", I can record ⌘⌥← / ⌘⌥→ just fine.

Previously, I used System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts to customize "Show Previous Tab" / "Show Next Tab" for "All Applications". I removed this, and it still didn't fix this issue in Xcode.

Comment: Are you open to using a third-party tool? (Karabiner-Elements or Hammerspoon)

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes I have Karabiner-Elements installed so I can use the function row on my Windows keyboard like Mac function keys. Can I use it to make this shortcut possible?

Comment: what's the default binding for this action? Or, if no default exists, what menu buttons are needed to be clicked to perform this action?